# How a status email should look like?

Tags: software-industry, performance

I'm working for small well growing company handling offshore projects.  Here I'm working as a Software Developer(not experienced) Here is my problem, Currently I have been shifted to a new project and here I used to send 3 types of status emails.

> 1. Daily Status email
> 2. Weekly Status email to my CEO
> 3. Weekly status email to my client

The format I'm using for Status Report is as follows:

**1. Daily Status email:**

```
  2. Task Completed  
      //tasks I have completed today
  3. In-Progess  
      //task I'm that I have in pipeline or working
  4. ToDos  
      //ToDos list of tasks
  5. Issues Facing  
      //Incase if I suffer I used to mention it here
```

**2. Weekly Status email to my CEO:**

```
> Very similar list in my Daily report that I have worked all long a
> week
```

**3. Weekly status email to my client(used to send a copy to my CEO):**

```
Here I never use the above format.  I used to type in a paragraph saying I 
have worked on these items, I am going to do these things on coming on
coming week and atlast if I need any review or any help I used to mention at 
last.
```

*My CEO feels I am doing seeing the big picture of the project, goofing emails, improper usage of English, can't even make a sentence,programming is not only the area,etc.,*

> Here I'm complaining about him. I can understand, he is trying to
>   improve my activities.  Before sending those email I even used to get
>   reviewed it with my seniors but still get punches from my boss because
>   of these thing I'm not able to concentrate in my programming.

I'm totally nowhere to share these things.  I am trying to read books to make good email, how to interact,etc.,  I can't really find one good approach.  Sometimes I even used to think I am not fit to make even sentences.  Please share some suggestion to overcome from this state, past 2 weeks I am really confused.  I don't want to give up and I even never thought of it, I like to work here.

Please pardon me for my bad English.  **I don't know where to tag it.  Feel free to edit my post with good English.**

Thanks for reading this.  I got three days of time, I'm ready to busy books if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think the layout of the status mails are the problem, have you considered taking some higher level english lessons? Whilst you are understandable it is not without some effort on the reader's part. The layout of the messages and the idea behind doing it is a good one though. Sorry if this comes across as a bit rude, it is not intended that way.

Comment: @RhysW Thanks.  But after all it revolves in my status emails when they point it out.  Thats why I put it here.  I'm confused, what to do next?  How can I improve?  How to equally spend time with my programming and Englisj?

Comment: I would split this question in two. The part about improving English in the Electronic Written form and take it to the English Learners SE and keep the part about a template for a Status Update Email here.

Comment: @user1671639 I have no say on what's mandatory but it would help your chances in getting help from a community where English Learners are their strong point.

Comment: @user1671639 im not sure what else to tell you, your boss comments on your english, you admit it could use work, and following it when reading (like in emails) is difficult. I really think that is the source of your problems, no amount of layout change in the status emails will change the ease at which people can understand it. It may sound harsh and you may not want to hear it, but communication is really, really important, especaially in the workplace where a miscommunication can cost people their jobs

Comment: Where are you located and what is your first language? A lot of people here in the US can complete a college degree and still not grasp English that well. It is frustrating for some. Take some classes, whether language, written language, or business communication. Continue to do your best and you'll start to improve. I've helped a coworker through something like this, and the fact that you're putting effort in with classes will show your character and instill confidence in those who are mentoring you.

Comment: Are the status emails something that you boss requested?  It seems to me they are saying stop sending them but I may be misreading your question

Comment: Find a mentor to help you and set proper (measurable) goals with your manager

Answer (score 4):

With all communications, there are two important parts - the sender, and the receiver.

The most important thing about any communications is that the sender is conveying what the receiver needs to hear, and that the receiver understands what is being conveyed by the sender.

In this case, you should talk to the recipient(s) of your Status Report and ask:

- What information do you need from me in my Status Report? and
- Is what I am sending understandable?

Talk with your boss, your CEO, and your client. Ask them how you are doing so far and what you need to change. If you hear that something is lacking, try another version, send it to them, and ask for their feedback. Keep it up until everyone has their needs met.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to ensure your boss does not feel forgotten about. Often in the world of business someone will take on a project and become so engrossed in completing the project that updates or set procedures may be forgotten about momentarily. This is not a good idea, especially if it is a long term project. Regular updates make people feel more involved in the project and it also serves to put their mind at ease that you are doing your best work possible.

By using a standard template this is a more effective communication tool than a simple email because you can arrange information in a more visually engaging way. This ensures that those you are communicating with are sure to take note of the most important information. Often times in a simple email, individuals will skim the contents in order to save time. When people do this they often miss important details. When all of the information can be conveyed precisely the first time, everyone saves time and gets more accomplished.

Have a look at [this link](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=5&sqi=2&ved=0CGcQFjAE&url=http://mifos.org/sites/rollout.mifos.org/files/Weekly%2520Status%2520Report%2520-%2520Template.doc&ei=0qQEUqqGL5Lo7Abf8oGoBw&usg=AFQjCNERIi8tXqx5dFJlreBO3PUdYOwUTA&sig2=ydUhsTisRA8R0hMDQCOYMQ) where you can download a template to use for yourself and below that you will find a status update provided as a sample of the end result.